# Error compiling tezos main net

Tags: tezos-client

I'm getting an error compiling the mainnet branch on Ubuntu 18.04 and also when I try Debian 9. Compiling from commit at the head of main net branch - `fce3f95a58234ce3d948a52469ccbf1c57024b9b`

The error is related to hidapi:

```
[ERROR] The sources of the following couldn't be obtained, aborting:
          - hidapi.1.0-1: Bad checksum
```

This has only just started occurring, I have usually been able to compile with the standard hidapi installed from apt-get install, however it appears the version installed is less than the one tezos is now looking for.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libhidapi-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libhidapi-dev is already the newest version (0.8.0~rc1+git20140818.d17db57+dfsg-2).
```

If I try to install the hidapi package with opam this happens:

```
$ opam install --verbose  hidapi
The following actions will be performed:
  ∗ install conf-pkg-config 1.1        [required by conf-hidapi]
  ∗ install dune            1.6.3      [required by jbuilder]
  ∗ install conf-m4         1          [required by ocamlfind]
  ∗ install conf-hidapi     0          [required by hidapi]
  ∗ install jbuilder        transition [required by hidapi]
  ∗ install ocamlfind       1.8.0      [required by base-bytes]
  ∗ install sexplib0        v0.11.0    [required by base]
  ∗ install base-bytes      base       [required by bigstring]
  ∗ install base            v0.11.1    [required by configurator]
  ∗ install bigstring       0.2        [required by hidapi]
  ∗ install stdio           v0.11.0    [required by configurator]
  ∗ install configurator    v0.11.0    [required by hidapi]
  ∗ install hidapi          1.0-1
===== ∗ 13 =====
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y

<><> Gathering sources ><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
[base.v0.11.1] found in cache
[bigstring.0.2] found in cache
[configurator.v0.11.0] found in cache
[dune.1.6.3] found in cache
[ocamlfind.1.8.0] found in cache
[sexplib0.v0.11.0] found in cache
[stdio.v0.11.0] found in cache
[ERROR] The sources of the following couldn't be obtained, aborting:
          - hidapi.1.0-1:
            https://github.com/vbmithr/ocaml-hidapi/archive/1.0.tar.gz (Bad checksum, expected md5=6197689cd0d5eae5316a4a2ba2a6f79f)

'opam install --verbose hidapi' failed.
```

Seems something funny is up with the source which was updated in the last 24 hours.

Any ideas how to resolve?

Comment: You are not the only one the build is broken right now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is due to a mistake I made when upgrading `hidapi` on OPAM. I was preparing a fix for compiling on FreeBSD (see [here](https://github.com/ocaml/opam-repository/pull/13836)), and for some reason re-created the old 1.0 tag which ended up changing the checksum.

You can either install hidapi by ignoring the checksum (`opam install hidapi --no-checksum`) or wait till the 1.1 hits OPAM (probably today).