# Error compiling tezos main net hidapi

Tags: tezos-client

Same issue as: [Error compiling tezos main net](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/error-compiling-tezos-main-net/1019#1019)

```
[ERROR] The sources of the following couldn't be obtained, aborting:
          - hidapi.1.0-1: Bad checksum
```

I did not update hidapi manually - this is on a fresh install.

I attempted to install hidapi manually `opam install hidapi` - last night but this didn't work. I raised an issue with the repository for opam and this was fixed today.

I can now run `opam install hidapi` - however the tezos build is still failing with the wrong checksum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the previous issue the mainnet HEAD hash had to be updated to d27205...

Please make sure your head points to there instead of fce3f95...

Reference:

https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/commit/d272059bf474018d0c39f5a6e60634a95f0c44aa