# Error when doing make build-deps for alphanet

Tags: node, alphanet

I am trying to build Tezos from sources, alphanet. When doing `make build-deps` here is the error I get:

```
[ERROR] The sources of the following couldn't be obtained, aborting:
      - hidapi.1.0-1: Bad checksum
```

I've been getting this since 2 or 3 days. Commands I tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/alphanet
git clean -dxf

opam update
opam upgrade
```

But it's still giving me the same error. Any idea why?

Comment: This is the same problem as in the other question, and the same fix is now on alphanet branch.

Comment: @Tom yup, I've addressed the problem to Tezos gitlab earlier today. All good now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the same in nature as in question

[Error compiling tezos main net hidapi](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/q/1029/118)

But the patch had not been included on the alphanet branch. A ticket was raised

https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/issues/504

And the mainnet patch was cherry picked onto the alphanet branch

https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/commit/4cad932e2c211cf699b9289ca167de44da3297b9

Comment: Thank you for all your help! :)